# Rust no_std find why global memory allocator is required

Tags: rust, memory-management, embedded

I'm writing Rust code for a platform which doesn't have support for std or alloc, so I have to use only core. Recently, my code has started producing this compile error:

```
error: no global memory allocator found but one is required; link to std or add `#[global_allocator]` to a static item that implements the GlobalAlloc trait

error: `#[alloc_error_handler]` function required, but not found
```

Is there a way I can get the rust compiler to tell me why a global memory allocator is required? Presumably, somewhere in my code or my dependencies something is attempting to allocate and that's causing it to go wrong, but I can't figure out where this is happening.

The only advice I saw online for this situation is to make a dummy custom allocator and then look through the compiled binary for references to it. However, I did this and am unable to find any reference to my custom allocator in the binary executable that it produced, which is making me more confused as to what's going on.

Comment: Is it possible that the allocation is in a non-referenced function, so that it would give the warning but be optimized out of the final binary?

Comment: @Carson That's definitely possible. I've got a lot of dependencies and I'm definitely not using everything, so there's quite a few functions like that, meaning there's a lot of cases where that could happen, but also a lot of space I'd have to search. Do you know any way to search for such functions effectively?

Comment: I'm unsure. It might be possible to define your global allocator as an empty struct and just make it `unreachable!()`, which might cause the places it's called to error out. Other possible idea is to comment out the non-referenced functions until the error disappears to find it.

Comment: Not `unreachable`, but either unconditionally returning null or aborting - panicking in allocator might be UB: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html#safety

Comment: @Cerberus I tried doing this (as I mentioned in my original post), and I couldn't find anything using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my case, it worked to use `cargo vendor` to download the source for all of my dependencies into a local directory, and then I used ripgrep to search through the dependencies for `extern crate alloc;`, which led me to one of my dependencies allocating without my knowledge. I don't know why the allocations didn't show up in the resulting binary, but this tool led me to the cause better than implementing a dummy allocator.